# Jquery and radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have some custom radio buttons which I created using js and some css, now I want when I click on a custom radio button, to set the clicked radio button as checked and the order ones as unchecked, so it should be only one checed radio button at the time.Here is what i tried to do, but doesn't work.

```
    $('.custom-checkbox li span, .bg-check').live('click', function(){


    $(this).parent().find('span').each(function(){

        $(this).addClass('checked').find('input:radio').attr('checked','');

    });     

    $(this).addClass('checked').find('input:radio').attr('checked','checked');



    return false;
});
```

Some please help me, I really don't get this.

//LE

```
function customCheckBox()
{
$('.custom-checkbox li').find('input:radio').hide().wrap('<span />');

$('.custom-checkbox li span, .bg-check').live('click', function(){


    $(this).parent().find('span').each(function(){

        $(this).removeClass('checked').find('input:radio').attr('checked',false);

    });     

    $(this).addClass('checked').find('input:radio').attr('checked',true);

    return false;
});

 }
```

This is how it works, I find all the radio inputs, and I wrap them with a `<span>` and the `<span>` element has some css styling...a custom image.

The Html

```
                    <ul class="custom-checkbox clearfix">
                    <li><input type="radio" name="ext" id="a" value=".ro"/><label for="a">.ro</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="ext" id="b" value=".com"/><label for="b">.com</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="ext" id="c" value=".net"/><label for="c">.net</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="ext" id="d" value=".org"/><label for="d">.org</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="ext" id="e" value=".info"/><label for="e">.info</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="ext" id="f" value=".biz"/><label for="f">.biz</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="ext" id="g" value=".us"/><label for="g">.us</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="ext" id="h" value=".eu"/><label for="h">.eu</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="ext" id="i" value=".mobi"/><label for="i">.mobi</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="ext" id="j" value=".name"/><label for="j">.name</label></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Posting the generated HTML as well would help.

Comment: Why are you using a generated `span` for the custom css, when you could simply apply a class/style to the radio-button's parent `li`?

Comment: That's how i've done it...but yes it will be better to do as you mentioned but I don't want to change the styles anymore. I just want to get it done now...

Comment: is IE6 a major concern? just asking.

Comment: I don't mean to be dense, but at the bottom of your question, could you clearly define what you want to happen when the user clicks on a radio-button (step-by-step)? It seems like you're reproducing the built-in radio-button behaviour...it's ten past four in the morning where I am, so I might just be tired...

Comment: @David Yes that's what I want to do, to select only a custom radio button at the time.

Comment: @Uffo, but that's part of the problem I'm having with your question: you're using custom radio-buttons to reproduce the functionality of the basic, built-in radio-buttons? I think I **must** be missing **something** because it feels like you're making things deliberately awkward for yourself. But, as I say, I might just be tired. If you can clarify, step-by-step, exactly what you want to happen when I click on a radio-button I'll try and help as best I can.

Comment: The goal is merely one of design, David. Most standard input elements are difficult/impossible to style. So ambitious designers want to replace those elements with custom markup that is easier to style. Much to the chagrin of their developers. ;) This is a source of many follow-up problems, when other JS wants to interact with change events, for example. But it's up to the one who does the replacement to decide whether neater styles are worth the technical headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, the attributes 'checked' and 'selected' are set with the values true and false.

Assuming that there's no other underlying problem with your code, that should fix it. If it still doesn't work, you need to give a little bit more context, i.e. markup and maybe supporting code.

For a first shot, you would adjust your code like this:

```
$('.custom-checkbox li span, .bg-check').live('click', function(){
  $(this)
    .closest('.custom-checkbox')
      .find('span')
        .removeClass('checked')
      .end()
    .end()
    .addClass('checked')
      .find('input:radio')
        .attr('checked',true)
      .end();
});
```

Comment: First of all in the each loop it should be $(this).removeClass...srry typo. I will edit the post with more..hang on

Comment: Still doesn't work, i can select multiple radio buttons at the same time http://screencast.com/t/NjY5YTQ1Yz

Comment: You were one level too low to do your reset loop. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: +1, sir. I must confess that I didn't even get the question... =)

Comment: Better make sure, that the correct hidden radio button is properly checked, too. I couldn't confirm that yet.

Comment: David, it is a bit convoluted, it's not just you. ;) Input element replacement is always a pain.

Comment: Last problem with radios not updating is fixed, too. Code simplified as well.